# Incorporar Smart Tags a un Control en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

En un proyecto de biblioteca de controles, tengo la siguiente clase HdsLabel que hereda de la clase Control para la creación de un control desde cero sin heredear de controles existentes. Lo que pretendo conseguir es que en tiempo de diseño pueda modificar propiedades del control a través de smart tags. El código de mi control es como sigue:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

namespace CoreEX.Controls
{
   [Designer(typeof(HdsLabelDesigner))]
   public class HdsLabel : Control
   {
      #region CONSTRUCTOR

      public HdsLabel()
      {
        
      }
      #endregion

      #region VARIABLES

      #endregion

      #region PROPERTIES

      #endregion

      #region EVENTS

      #endregion

      #region DRAWING
      
      #endregion

  }
  public class HdsLabelDesigner : ControlDesigner
  {
    private DesignerActionListCollection actionLists;

    public override DesignerActionListCollection ActionLists
    {
        get
        {
            if (actionLists == null)
            {
                actionLists = new DesignerActionListCollection();
                actionLists.Add(new MyActionList((HdsLabel)Control));
            }
            return actionLists;
        }
    }
  }
  public class MyActionList : DesignerActionList
  {
    private HdsLabel myControl;
    private DesignerActionUIService designerActionSvc = null;

    public MyActionList(HdsLabel control) : base(control)
    {
        myControl = control;
        designerActionSvc = (DesignerActionUIService)GetService(typeof(DesignerActionUIService));
    }

    private PropertyDescriptor GetPropertyByName(string propName)
    {
        PropertyDescriptor prop = default(PropertyDescriptor);
        prop = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(myControl)[propName];
        if (prop == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Property", propName);
        }
        else
        {
            return prop;
        }
    }
    public override DesignerActionItemCollection GetSortedActionItems()
    {
        DesignerActionItemCollection items = new DesignerActionItemCollection();
        
        items.Add(new DesignerActionPropertyItem("BackColor", "Background color"));
    
        return items;
    }
    public Color BackColor
    {
        get { return myControl.BackColor; }
        set { GetPropertyByName("BackColor").SetValue(myControl, value); }
    }
  }
}
```

Por más que reviso el código creo que está todo correcto, pero a la hora de compilar y añadir el control a un formulario no aparece la típica flechita en la parte superior derecha del control en tiempo de diseño que me permita acceder a las smart tags. No entiendo qué pueda estar sucediendo.

Answer (score 0):

Después de no pocos quebraderos de cabeza, he podido resolver el problema cambiando tanto el proyecto de biblioteca de controles como el proyecto para testarlo a la plataforma .NET Framework 4.8 antes tenía ambos en .NET 6.0 No entiendo por qué el código va en una y en otra no pero al menos he subsanado el problema y entiendo que el código era correcto porque ahora funciona como se espera.